# Finding out the value of $x$

Tags: geometry

In the diagram below, the segments shown are tangents to the circle. To  find the value of $x$ what method will be easiest?

[image]

Are the three edges of the triangle the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lines tangent to the same circle from the same point are equal. Therefore, $x=2+3=5$.

Answer (score 1):

The length of two intersecting tangent lines are equal. So, one side is length $2+4=6$. Another side is of length $3+4=7$. The final side, $x$ has length $2+3=5$. So $x=5$.